# How to use Xcode to populate PDF and HTML templates with user-defined variable data

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, templates, pdf

Okay, so I have developed my entire user interface with xcode. I have set various text fields as variables, and I am trying to figure out how to populate either PDF templates or HTML templates with this user defined variable data.

First, which would be better for printing (with a hardware printer, not in the coding sense)- PDF or HTML?

Second, is it possible to populate the user's input to either a PDF or HTML template? I am writing a legal software suite in which the PDF/HTML templates will not need to be visible in the interface itself, only when print previewing, or exporting the templates to another source (iPad, laptop, etc)?

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Mitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to create a HTML document but for printing, PDF is better. This is because, as far as I know, HTML is rendered differently depending on the browser but PDF will always look the same.

To create HTML you could just write plain text to a file so you could write a template before-hand, read that template into a string in memory, search for fields and insert the user's data into that string, and write a new file.

For PDF it would be more complex. I would suggest having a look at [PDF-kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html) for high-level and [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101) for low-level PDF programming.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right, HTML will not only vary according to the user's browser but also the browser preferences (margins, whether or not the title, time, and date should be printed with the HTML, etc). I will have a look at the PDF-kit.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote razpdf app extension (static library) to make it easy to add PDF output to iOS apps.  www.raz.com. Define a page sized view in IB, add dynamic data, call add page, save pdf on device. mail it to users. Check out docs and evaluation copy.